# Default image showing up in panel for applications

Tags: gnome-panel

[image]

My application has a *check-for-updates* option clicking on which a JFrame appears asking the user if they want to update the app or not.

When this frame appears the corresponding panel image for it is some default image given by Ubuntu. I want my app logo to appear here instead. What should I do to customize this image?

Comment: If you wrote this program we would need to see the code to even start to help.

Comment: Just to help with the terminology, that panel is called the "dock", and that image in that context is called an "icon" or, a "launcher icon".

Comment: @David I found the answer. I have to use ImageIcon seperately and add it to the JFrame to eliminate the default icon. Thank you both for the response.

Comment: @Levente I found the answer. I have to use ImageIcon seperately and add it to the JFrame to eliminate the default icon. Thank you both for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Everything I mentioned in the question is in reference to a JFrame. The Frame on opening up shows up with a default icon in Ubuntu panel. I want my app logo  to appear in here instead. This was my issue and I fixed it.

This is the code I used to add icon to my JFrame.

```
 ImageIcon img=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/leaf.png"));
        frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());
```

This image will never show up in JFrame but will appear as icon in the Ubuntu panel whenever the JFrame is opened.